# How do I assign values to an object based on a certain order of relative values in another object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm attempting to write a function that will mutate an object of key value pairs that represent each month in a year and the number of weeks in each month. The example input looks like this, where each key is the month and year, and the corresponding value is the number of weeks in that month:

```
 { '2018-01': 4, '2018-02': 4, '2018-03': 4, '2018-04': 5 ... }
```

The goal is to set the number of weeks in each month based on a '4-5-4' pattern (if you've ever heard of a retail calendar, you know what I'm talking about), with an optional parameter to start the pattern at any month the user decides. So if the user decides that February is their start month, the above object would transform to this:

```
{ '2018-01': 4 '2018-02': 4, '2018-03': 5, '2018-04': 4 ... }
```

You can imagine that after the fourth key value pair, the pattern of '4-5-4' repeats again. I'm using moment.js to parse the inputs of user values to dates (the optional parameter of start month is an input like "February"). The part of writing this I'm finding most tricky is iterating through the input object in order of the months as they appear on the calendar, knowing full well that objects aren't inherently ordered. I can view a distant MVP that is many nested conditionals and loops, but I'm sure there must be a more efficient solution to this.

One attempt I made looked like this, where I imported an array of month names, ensuring ordered iteration as I cycled through the object:

```
if (weeksFormat === '4-4-5') {
    for (let i = orderedMonthNames.indexOf(startMonth); i < orderedMonthNames.length; i += 3) {
        months[moment(orderedMonthNames[i]).format('YYYY-M')] = 4
        months[moment(orderedMonthNames[i + 1]).format('YYYY-M')] = 4
        months[moment(orderedMonthNames[i + 2]).format('YYYY-M')] = 5

        for (let x = i - 1; x >= 0; x -= 3) {
            months[moment(orderedMonthNames[x]).format('YYYY-M')] = 4
            months[moment(orderedMonthNames[x - 1]).format('YYYY-M')] = 4
            months[moment(orderedMonthNames[x - 2]).format('YYYY-M')] = 5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: please add it to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks :D I'm quite new to asking questions on SO

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you should be aware of:

- Objects keys are not sortable and objects are not iterable, you want
  to use arrays for that
- You should avoid mutating objects

If I understand the problem I would take a different approach:
Have a sorted array with all the months:

```
const months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec',];
```

Use a function to rearrange the months starting from the optional `startMonth`

```
function rearrange(startMonth) {
  const index = months.indexOf(startMonth);
  const before = months.slice(0, index);
  const after = months.slice(index);
  return [].concat(after, before);
}
```

use it

```
rearrange(‘Feb’);
// ["Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan"]
```

Now you can simply iterate over this and use your 4-5-4 pattern, since it comes in multiple of 3 you can use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

```
const monthly = {};
const rearrangeed = rearrange('Feb');
rearrangeed.forEach(function(month, index) {
  monthly[month] = (index%3 === 1) ? 5 : 4;
});

console.log(monthly)
// {Feb: 4, Mar: 5, May: 4, Jun: 4, Jul: 5, ... }
```

Finally, using again the ordered months array you can generate the final array with all you need

```
const ordered = [];
months.forEach(function(monthName, index) {
  const weeks = monthly[monthName];
  const month = moment(monthName).format('YYYY-MM');
  ordered.push({ month, weeks });
});

console.log(ordered);
// [{month: "2018-01", weeks: 4}, {month: "2018-02", weeks: 4}, {month: "2018-03", weeks: 5} … ];
```

Does it make sense to you?